# Is there a way to identify which JS is overwriting window.console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to troubleshoot a page with lots of JS, including ads, and something is causing window.console to be replaced which suppresses the typical console logging output that I would want to see.

Is there a way to identify which JS is overwriting window.console? Maybe trigger a breakpoint only when typeof(window.console) is modified?

Comment: Pottentially ES6's [object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) may help? edit: Just realised its deprecated but of its still available it may do for debugging.

Comment: You can use define property to add setter descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! And I think I can help. 
Use Object.defineProperty https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
to recreacte .log property.

Smth like this:

```
        Object.defineProperty(console, "log", {
            set: function () { throw 'Hoh!' }
        });


        console.log = 'abc';
```